# Is Gelbooru a Japanese pun like how Danbooru is Cardboard?

Tags: puns

Is Gelbooru (ゲルブール) a Japanese pun like how [Danbooru](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/sites/danbooru) is Cardboard (段ボール)?

I don't think so, especially with that barely attested transliteration, but my only other guess on the name origin is that it's using "Gel" like a [Brit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gel#Noun_2), a.k.a a Board of Girls, which also makes sense.

Comment: FYI I'm not sure of the pronunciation, but if it is ジェルボール, the first thing that comes to my mind is a type of detergent.

Comment: @sundowner - A.k.a Gelball? https://ariel.jp/ja-jp/shop/category/gelball, hmm. Well, that *would* be a pun. But it doesn't have backup like Danbooru's SFW Facebook of Cardboard Boxes... https://www.facebook.com/Danbooru/

Answer (score -1):

Girl or Gal Board.
Its ellegant.
Way more gallant & gracious thant some gullible geeknerds who seriously swear it means gayball.
I suppose its because they watched too much doragon booru.